# USA zipcodes shapefile

Tags: shapefile, united-states

I have excel with zip codes and their respective latitude and longitude details, how can I plot them on arcgis pro in the polygon/polyline shape

Comment: Zipcodes aren't polygons -- They're polylines (delivery routes) and points (PO boxes). And they change, as population does, so there isn't a "the USA zipcode shapefile" -- At best, it's the *current* zipcode shapefile (which you seem to have).

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! If you are looking for open data then opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask

Comment: thank you for the feedback, than how do I plot my zipcodes on map in the form of polylines in arcgis pro?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.